# how to open multi tabs in chrome with selenium with different session

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I need to login to multiple accounts (same website) at once and I need to open multiple tabs.
Each tab needs to be independent so that I can login to different accounts.

is there any way to achieve this using selenium or any other automation tool.

Greetings.

Comment: Would different window works for you ?

Comment: if it's gonna give me a new session .. yes

Comment: all you want to do is to login with same creds in a multiple browser window within same test method ? Could you tag your binding language as well ?

Comment: am using python

Comment: if I automate the login in a window and opened new window .. would it give me to login again with a different account?

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed you can by using chrome driver and selenium
code:

driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="ChromeDriverExeLocation")
driver1= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="ChromeDriverExeLocation")

driver.get("googleloginform")
driver1.get("googleloginform2")